# scalajs getCause on Ajax.post onFailure

Tags: ajax, post, error-handling, scala.js

Try to get the cause for an Ajax.post failure (using Scala.Js) but get only the class name:

```
Ajax.post(
  url = "...",
  data = "...",
  headers = Map("Content-Type"->"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Csrf-Token" -> "...")
).map(_.responseText).map(
  content => content match {
    case _                  => ...
  }
).onFailure {
  case err => log.info(s"failure ${err.toString} ${err.getCause} ${err.getMessage}")
}
```

I get:

```
failure org.scalajs.dom.ext.AjaxException null null
```

Is it possible to get the cause?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. As the `AjaxException` can not be constructed with a cause:

```
case class AjaxException(xhr: dom.XMLHttpRequest) extends Exception {
  def isTimeout = xhr.status == 0 && xhr.readyState == 4
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems I have to check Ajax Server status and ready State for more details.